# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker enabledDates not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I recieve array from mysql database with dates which I need to enable in datepicker and Bootstrap 3 Datepicker doesnt accept it.

```
var datesArray = [];
oReq.onload = function () {
    var arr = $.parseJSON(this.responseText);
    $(arr).each(function (index, el) {
        datesArray.push(moment(el).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
    });
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        locale: 'ru',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        minDate: new Date(),
        enabledDates: datesArray
    });
};
```

Here how it looks with the creation of array and with its passage to the Bootstrap 3 Datepicker.

And for some reason it displays that all dates are disabled.

Comment: does datesArray contains only the future dates ??

Comment: yeah it contains only future dates